# StageDisplayState.FULLSCREEN vs StageDisplayState.FULLSCREEN_INTERACTIVE

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, stage, stagedisplaystate

What's the difference between the the two display states?

Comment: Was it really so hard to check official reference?

Comment: Googled this question, this post was the first hit and the answer was presented on a silver platter for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN` doesn't support keyboard interactivity.  `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE` does, but it works only with Adobe AIR.

Source: [Adobe ActionScript3 Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/StageDisplayState.html)

Comment: i'm pretty sure some of the keys work in full screen non-AIR .swfs since Flash Player 10.  if i recall correctly, i believe fullscreen keyboard functionality is limited to non-printing keys: arrows, space, shift, enter and maybe tab.

Comment: You're probably partially right. I've tested it today - I've placed a TextField in my application and have set the stage's display state to `FULL_SCREEN`. I could freely edit the content of the TextField, there were no problems with it.

Comment: According to Adobe: "As of Flash Player 11.3, this capability is supported in both AIR applications and browser-based applications."

So feel free to make phony login screens and harvest people's passwords. ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. `StageDisplayState.FULLSCREEN` is available in both AIR and normal Flex web apps, Keyboard is not traced
2. `StageDisplayState.FULLSCREEN_INTERACTIVE` available ONLY IN AIR and it allows you to used the keyboard. for ex you can type inside a TextInput in FS only with FullScreenInteractive.

Answer (score 0):

StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE can work in flex webapp.when you compile web app,you just need to replace the playerglobal.swc by high version,like 11.7。。。
hope it helps you